# Python file does not run on Ubuntu on server but runs in local on Mac

Tags: python, macos, mongodb, ubuntu, azure

This is the code where I'm dumping all the data from .csv file into mongodb. What is strange is that it runs perfectly well on my mac but when I upload this code to Windows Azure running ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS only the main code gets executed and function is not called. Here's the code I'm using

```
import csv,json,glob,traceback
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
import sys
import string


def make_document(column_headers,columns,timestamps):
    #assert len(column_headers)==len(columns)
    lotr = filter(lambda x: x[0] is not None,zip(column_headers,columns))
    final = []
    #print lotr
    if not timestamps=={}:
        for k,v in lotr:
            try:
                tformat = timestamps[k]
                time_val = datetime.datetime.strptime(v,tformat)
                final.append((k,time_val))
            except KeyError:
                final.append((k,v))
        return dict(final)
    else:
        return dict(lotr)

def keep_printable_only(s):
    return filter(lambda x: x in string.printable,s)

def perform(conf):
    client = MongoClient(conf["server"],conf["port"])
    db = client[conf["db"]]
    collection = db[conf["collection"]]
    files = glob.glob(conf["data_form"])
    column_headers = conf["columns"]
    csv_opts = {}
    for k,v in conf["csv_options"].items():
        csv_opts[str(k)]=str(v)
    for infile in files:
        #print conf["csv_options"]
        inCSV = csv.reader(open(infile,'rU'),**csv_opts)
        counter = 0
        for record in inCSV:
            yield record
            counter +=1
            if counter==2:
                print record
                #sys.exit(0)
            record= map(keep_printable_only,record)
            try:
                doc = make_document(column_headers,record,conf["timestamp_columns"])
                collection.insert(doc)
            except :
                print "error loading one of the lines : "
                print traceback.format_exc()





if __name__=='__main__':
    print"reads all data files of same format as given in column mapping and dumps them to a mongo collection"
    print "uses conf.json.test as config file"
    conf = json.load(open('./conf.json.txt'))
    for row in perform(conf):
        record= map(keep_printable_only,row)
```

When I run this on Azure, mongo collection is not created and the code terminates after printing the two lines in main code. I have no idea as to why this is happening.

Comment: Have you added debug output to your script to see up to where it comes?  (Just add `print` statements at vital points.)  Have you aborted your script using `C-c` and viewed the stack trace?  Can you post that?  By "the code stops" do you mean it terminates or it halts and hangs?

Comment: I added some print statements in perform(conf) function but they are not printed and it seems that the code terminates after executing statements in the main function without calling the function perform(conf). Unfortunately, the code terminates instantly so I could not use C-c to view the stack trace. –

Comment: Because you are not passing the correct file name for your json file. Confirm that is actually the path.

Comment: You should get an `IOError` and thus a decent stack trace automatically if just the file name is wrong and the file not existing.

Comment: Actually I realised that file path and name is correct but file path inside the conf.json.txt file was incorrect for finding the actual csv files!!! Very simple mistake but I'm wondering what's the best way to debug those kind of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug output would be very useful, in the form of a stack trace, as commented by @Alfe.

Further than that, it looks like your code stops at the line where you try to access a local file to read the configuration. Make sure that you can access the filesystem that way in Azure; sometimes providers put very strict walls between your code and the actual machine.

You can make your code more portable by using:

```
import os
import os.path

conf_filehandle = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'conf.json'))
conf = json.load(conf_filehandle)
```

Of course, you should also make sure that you have uploaded the JSON file to Azure :)

Comment: Great, I'll use this method. The issue was in fact that the file path in my conf.json.txt file was not correct for finding the csv files.

Comment: A minor comment: JSON _is_ text, but the usual extension for JSON files is `.json`, not `.txt` :)